# Cannot release shared memory created by CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile in C++

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I am learning working with shared memory in C++. I found that under Windows I need to use CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile functions. I want to share array of char so part of my code is:

```
HANDLE hBuffer = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size, bufferName);
char * buffer = (char *) MapViewOfFile(hBuffer, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, size);
```

(there is checking for NULLs of course) and at the end of using shared memory I call:

```
UnmapViewOfFile(buffer); // returned true
CloseHandle(hBuffer); // returned true also
```

But in Resource monitor I can see that there was no memory released. When it is called several times, the allocated memory of application is increasing but there is no releasing. What am I doing wrong? Or is there another function to release shared memory?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What are your reading in Resource monitor? Are you looking at the commit size or the working set size?

Comment: The memory will not be released until all applications accessing it releases it/closes their handles.. For example, two applications map share one memory map. One application closes its handle, the memory map will still exist until the second application does the same thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well, I am looking to both columns because I don't exactly understand what is the difference between them. But the situation is same. Both of these columns are increased. But definitely is something wrong in my code because if I don't use shared memory but just buffer = new char[size], after delete[] buffer I can see in resource monitor how the memory is released.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: I don't have any second application. I just for practise created the shared memory and now I want release it.

Comment: Your code looks find (well,... you mispelled HANDLE), you can use procexp.exe from sysinternals to find your HANDLE by name (if it is not found then it was closed), also observe on Performance tab how Virtual Size of you app changes, there is also Handles count that should change accordingly.

Comment: Also, observe what will happen after you execute `memset(buffer,0,size);` after MapViewOfFile - this is actually when system will commit memory and when your workin set will rise.

Comment: My above comment is wrong, CreateFileMapping by default applies SEC_COMMIT which commits memory. But I suppose your memory is paged until memset is called, after that call paged pages are moved to physical memory, which rises working set.... if I am not wrong...

Comment: @marcin_j: Thanks a lot, you helped me. First I tried check handle in procexp. It was ok. Then I checked virtual size after before and after calling MapViewOfFile. I saw the virtual size was increased by specifed value "size" which now I set to 256 MB to see difference good. But in resource monitor the memory increased just a little bit - a few KB. And that was my mistake in code - I forgot delete some memory allocated in previous testing, so I thought it was unreleased shared memory. After calling `memset(buffer, 0, size)` the memory was allocated so I was able to see it in resource monitor.

Comment: @marcin_j: Can you explain me how it exactly works, please? After calling `MapViewOfFile` is Virtual size increased - the size which is "prepared" to be allocated? And after calling `memset` this memory is allocated in working set? In commit memory was no changes.... but important is that it work and memory is released in the end.

Comment: My understanding of this is as I have written above, MapViewOfFile will reserve and commit memory, but it will be paged. Once you use it, system generated page faults (you can see it in procexp), and copies pages from page file to physical memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to marcin_j:

> Your code looks find (well,... you mispelled HANDLE), you can use
>   procexp.exe from sysinternals to find your HANDLE by name (if it is
>   not found then it was closed), also observe on Performance tab how
>   Virtual Size of you app changes, there is also Handles count that
>   should change accordingly.
>
> Also, observe what will happen after you execute
>   memset(buffer,0,size); after MapViewOfFile - this is actually when
>   system will commit memory and when your workin set will rise.
>
> My above comment is wrong, CreateFileMapping by default applies
>   SEC_COMMIT which commits memory. But I suppose your memory is paged
>   until memset is called, after that call paged pages are moved to
>   physical memory, which rises working set.... if I am not wrong...